# Python with Selenium : pagination issue

Tags: python, selenium, pagination

I am trying to scrape using Selenium in Python where I am trying to loop through landing pages on bigkinds.or.kr by clicking on the increasing number button.

The next page is located in the following HTML according to the Chrome Inspector:

```
<div class="newsPage">
    <div class="btmDelBtn"> 
                             ...</div>
<span>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="current">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getSearchResultNew(2)">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getSearchResultNew(3)">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getSearchResultNew(4)">4</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getSearchResultNew(5)">5</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getSearchResultNew(6)">6</a>
</span>
```

I am not getting success in crawling by clicking next page. Please help me.
Here is my code:

```
url = "https://www.bigkinds.or.kr/main.do"
browser.get(url)

...

currentPageElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/span/a[2]")

print(currentPageElement)

currentPageNumber = int(currentPageElement.text)

print(currentPageNumber)
```

In xpath, "/span/a[**2**]" is a page number. How can I make loop for this xpath.

Comment: 1. you are trying to convert an element's text to an integer: int(currentPageElement.text).  2. you never call `click()` method anywhere in your code even though the question is about clicking.

Comment: In xpath, "/span/a[2]" is a page number. How can I make loop for this xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

url = "https://www.bigkinds.or.kr/main.do"
browser.get(url)
page_count = 1
while True:
    # Increase page_count value on each iteration on +1
    page_count += 1
    # Do what you need to do on each page
    # Code goes here
    try:
        # Clicking on "2" on pagination on first iteration, "3" on second...
        browser.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_count)).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # Stop loop if no more page available
        break
```

*Update*

If you still want to use search by `XPath`, you might need to replace line

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_count)).click()
```

with line

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@onclick="getSearchResultNew(%s)"]' % page_count).click()
```

...or if you want to use your absolute `XPath` (not the best idea), you can try

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/di‌​v[2]/div[7]/span/a[%s​]" % page_count).click()
```

Comment: Thank you. but I want to know increasing number in xpath.  currentPageElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/span/a[**2**]")

Comment: Welcome. You can mark my answer as Accepted if it solved your problem